# How to unformat a formatted String

Tags: java, android

Hi I have formatted a string using the below code

> mForecastStr = String.format("%s - %s - %s/%s",dateView.getText(),
>                       forecastView.getText(), highView.getText(),
>                       lowView.getText());

Now I want to separate the values from **mForecastStr**

Like the value before the first hyphen, then the second hyphen and the n the value after the third hyphen.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It's possible and sometimes it's necessary, but since you already have the values there may be a better way.

Comment: If you insist on finding the values from the formatted string, either look into regular expressions, or simply split the string by the hyphen.

Comment: The data is stored in a formatted manner in the string, I need o retrieve it from the formatted string.

Answer (score 1):

To get an array of string with the split values:

```
String[] arrForecast = mForecastStr.split(" - ");
```

Now `arrForecast[0]` will contain the first value, `arrForecast[1]` the second one and `arrForecast[2]` the third one.